# datetime vs pandas.to_datetime on path.getmtime

Tags: pandas, datetime

pandas.to_datetime is not inferring the os.path.getmtime time stamps correctly. Is there a way to do this using to_datetime instead of datetime.date?

```
from datetime import date
from pandas import to_datetime
from os.path import getmtime
​
a = getmtime('example.txt')
a
1542074774.0

date.fromtimestamp(a).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'2018-11-12'

pandas.to_datetime(a).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
'1970-01-01'
```

Comment: `pandas.to_datetime(a, unit='s').strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` right from the [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) documentation under `Using a unix epoch time`

Comment: Chris is correct on the unit='s' solution. There is no explanation in the documentation as to what unit='s' means or when it should be used.

Comment: It stands for seconds